# display:inline-block is not working in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Here is my `Navbar` component:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='Navbar'>
      <ul className='list-group w-75 mx-auto'>
        <li className='list-group-item'>
          <i className='fab fa-twitter' id='twitter' />
        </li>
        {nav.map((item) => (
          <Nav key={v4()} iconClass={item.iconClass} name={item.name} />
        ))}
        <li className='mx-auto'>
          <button className='btn butn p-3'>Tweet</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

And my `Nav` component:

```
const Nav = ({ iconClass, name }) => {
return (
    <li onClick={onClick} className='d-flex align-items-center list-group-item'>
      <i className={iconClass} />
      <span>{name}</span>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

All `li`'s are `display: block`. I want them to be `display: inline-block`. But it is not working. I've tried using Bootstrap, in my own `.scss` file, inline styling. But no change. Can you help, please?

Comment: Have you tried using`<ul className='list-group list-group-horizontal w-75 mx-auto'>`? According to the docs, `list-group-horizontal` will change vertical list items to horizontal. [List Group > Horizontal](<ul className='list-group w-75 mx-auto'>)

Comment: Have you tried with ```display:flex``` or ```d-flex``` || ```dispaly:inline-flex``` or ```d-inline-flex```. Since flex can be a better alternative for ```display:inline-block```. Apart from this, you will be able to manage different position without any much of additional css.

Comment: I have tried both `d-inline-flex` and `list-group-horizontal`. `d-flex`  is not working, `list-group-horizontal` is not what I want. I just want to make `li`'s inline-block @terrymorse

Comment: You can't just add `display:inline-block` to list group items to force them to display horizontally. It will have no effect. Use the classes that Bootstrap provides. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `style="display: inline-block"` to Bootstrap list-group items will have no effect, because Bootstrap `list-group` uses flexbox, with items oriented vertically (column):

```css
.list-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

If you want the items in a list group to be horizontal rather than vertical, add the `list-group-horizontal` class to the list-group element, which changes the default list-group flex direction from `column` (vertical) to `row` (horizontal).

To illustrate this, here is the HTML that would be produced by the code in the question above:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/brands.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/solid.min.css">
</head>

<body class="p-4">

  <h4>Existing Navbar</h4>

  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="list-group w-75 mx-auto" style="background-color: #e0e0e0">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter" id="twitter"></i>
      </li>
      <!-- some items to stand in for Nav components -->
      <li onclick="alert('ambulance')" class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item">
        <i class="fas fa-ambulance"></i>
      </li>
      <li onclick="alert('apple')" class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item">
        <i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i>
      </li>
      <li onclick="alert('baby carriage')" class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item">
        <i class="fas fa-baby-carriage"></i>
      </li>
      <li onclick="alert('biking')" class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item">
        <i class="fas fa-biking"></i>
      </li>
      <li class='mx-auto'>
        <button class='btn butn p-3'>Tweet</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice that the orientation of the list-group items is vertical.

Here is that same HTML result, with `list-group-horizontal` added:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/brands.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/solid.min.css">

<body class="p-4">

  <h4>Modified Navbar</h4>

  <p>Changes:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Removed "d-flex" from all list group items (had no effect)</li>
    <li>Added "list-group-horizontal" to ul (puts all li elements on same line)
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="list-group w-75 mx-auto list-group-horizontal" style="background-color: #e0e0e0">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter" id="twitter"></i>
      </li>
      <!-- some items to stand in for Nav components -->
      <li onclick="alert('ambulance')" class="align-items-center list-group-item">
        <i class="fas fa-ambulance"></i>
      </li>
      <li onclick="alert('apple-alt')" class="align-items-center list-group-item">
        <i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i>
      </li>
      <li onclick="alert('baby-carriage')" class="align-items-center list-group-item">
        <i class="fas fa-baby-carriage"></i>
      </li>
      <li onclick="alert('biking')" class="align-items-center list-group-item">
        <i class="fas fa-biking"></i>
      </li>
      <li class='mx-auto'>
        <button class='btn butn p-3'>Tweet</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

For completeness, here is the code from the question, with `list-group-horizontal` added to the `<ul>`:

```js
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='Navbar'>
      <ul className='list-group w-75 mx-auto list-group-horizontal'>
        <li className='list-group-item'>
          <i className='fab fa-twitter' id='twitter' />
        </li>
        {nav.map((item) => (
          <Nav key={v4()} iconClass={item.iconClass} name={item.name} />
        ))}
        <li className='mx-auto'>
          <button className='btn butn p-3'>Tweet</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

And the Nav component, with `d-flex` removed from the `<li>`:

```js
const Nav = ({ iconClass, name }) => {
return (
    <li onClick={onClick} className='align-items-center list-group-item'>
      <i className={iconClass} />
      <span>{name}</span>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

Comment: @ShahobiddinKhusniddinov Great, thanks for letting me know.